# Cannot copy and paste any more from local pc to remote desktop windows 2008 server

Tags: windows-server-2008

I could do so a few days ago and now I realize I can't do it any more. How can I make this behavior come back ?

Comment: What error messages do you get. Also check the event log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RDP clipboard on the client or the server has crashed. You could try rebooting the client or the server.

Comment: You're right :)

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this without rebooting either by killing the process "rdclip" on the server and then disconnecting the RDP session and reconnecting; a new one will be spawned and you'll be back in business.